# Loop to create Multiple JSON files from the CSVs saved in multiple folder

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi all can help to enhanced my python code for creating *JSON* files. I want to create loop that creates *json* (different *json* for each of the folder) from the *csv* files save in different folder and  and then save all the *json* in the one common folder. Right now I am using below code and changing the path last two digits manually to create *json* one by one that is very tedious task.

Or is possible to create same task in R?

```py
import csv
import json
import glob
import os

class csv2jsonindirectory():
    def Python_trial(self):
        # Update the following variable with the path in windows and replace
        # every "\" with "/".
        path_to_folder = "C:\\Users\\CSVs\\AO"
        csv_files_in_folder = path_to_folder + '/*.csv'
        csvfilenames = []
        i = 1
        mydict = {}
        for filename in glob.glob(csv_files_in_folder):
            csvfilenames.append(os.path.splitext(filename)[0])
            rows = []
        for i in range(len(csvfilenames)):
            with open(csvfilenames[i] + ".csv", "r") as f:
                csvreader = csv.DictReader(f)
                rows = list(csvreader)
                mydict["chartdiv" + str(i + 1)] = rows

        print(mydict)

        with open(csvfilenames[0] + ".json", 'w') as f:
            json.dump(mydict, f, indent= 4)


dd = csv2jsonindirectory()
dd.Python_trial()
```

Comment: Tagging questions with two languages is almost never a good idea. See [When is it appropriate to tag multiple languages in my question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354931/when-is-it-appropriate-to-tag-multiple-languages-in-my-question)

Answer (score 1):

Break it down into smaller problems.

I'm going to drop the class, because it doesn't seem to be needed. Also, I'm going to use `pathlib` instead of `os.path`.

```
import csv
import json
import pathlib
```

First, define a function that takes a path to the csv file and returns the contents as a list of dicts:

```
def load_csv(filepath):
    with filepath.open("r") as f:
        csvreader = csv.DictReader(f)
        return list(csvreader)
```

Now define a function that takes a path to a directory and loads all the csv files in that directory.

```
def load_all_csv_in_dir(dirpath):
    csv_map = {}
    
    for counter, filepath in enumerate(dirpath.glob("*.csv"), 1):
        csv_map[f"chartdiv{counter}"] = load_csv(filepath)
        
    return csv_map
```

Define a function that takes a directory; gathers all the csv files for each subdirectory; and saves them to a json file.

```
def gather_csv_from_subdirs(rootpath):
    for path in rootpath.iterdir():
        if not path.is_dir():
            continue

        csv_map = load_all_csv_in_dir(path)

        if not csv_map:
            continue

        jsonfile = rootpath / f"{path.parts[-1]}.json"
        with jsonfile.open("w") as f:
            json.dump(csv_map, f, indent=4)
```

Lastly,

```
gather_csv_from_subdirs(pathlib.Path("C:/Users/CSVs"))
```